# cartopy contours don't wrap around longitudes

Tags: python, contour, cartopy

I am trying to plot sea ice contours in North Polar Stereo projections using cartopy but there's this strange behavior where the contours don't wrap around at 180 degrees. I looked at another post ([Strange behavior with contours in Cartopy polar stereographic plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238645/strange-behavior-with-contours-in-cartopy-polar-stereographic-plot)) that suggested to change my longitude to 0-360 but if i do that i have the same exact issue but at longitude 0 instead of 180.

(using the same data, I never had that issue using basemap)

sea_ice, LO and LA are matrices of size (448, 304) and most importantly, LA and LO are not regularly spaced lat and lon, it's in polar projection so I can't use add_cyclic_point.

Here is my plotting code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.NorthPolarStereo(true_scale_latitude=70))
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 16,'rotation':0}
ax.coastlines('10m')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 55, 90], crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor = '0.75')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS,facecolor='blue')
```

cc=plt.contour(LO, LA, sea_ice, levels=[15], colors='m', linewidth=3, transform=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())

[Contours with my longitudes from -180 to 180](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnern.jpg)

[Contours with my longitude from 0 to 360](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1nzd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

We both used the same NSIDC daily dataset.

Try

```
ax.contour(xgrid, ygrid, sea_ice, [15], transform=cartopy.crs.epsg(3411))
```

Agreed the lats, lons and sea_ice are 2D by xgrid and ygrid, not lat and lon. You then call the transform specific to the datasets epsg tag, which the aggributes suggest is 3411.

srid : urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3411